# How do I check the whole string between duplicates?

Tags: python, string, list, duplicates

Leetcode #3 Longest Substring Without Repeating Characters

Question:
Given a string, find the length of the longest substring without repeating characters.

My code:

```
def len_of_substring(s): 
    list_int = []
    st = ''

    for n in range(0, len(s)): 
        if s[n] not in st:
            st=st+str(s[n])
            list_int.append(len(st))
        else: 
            #list_int.append(len(st))
            st=s[n]
    return(max(list_int))

len_of_substring('dvdf')
```

The code should return 3 for 'vdf' but my code only returns 2. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.  Your code appears to be appropriately minimal in implementation, but I don't know how many people will do the work to reverse-engineer your logic, given the useless variable names, and the lack of debugging so far.  Stick in some `print` statements to track execution and data flow; show us where the logic goes wrong.

Comment: Could it be because you aren't testing `vdf`, but `dvdf`?

Comment: @GAEfan It is supposed to return 3 even when testing 'dvdf'

Comment: Yeah, I was reading your code, and not the original task. Your code just counts until a repeat character.

Answer (score 1):

You never append the last substring that you find to `list_int`. You could fix that by after the for loop including something like the following:

```
if st:
    list_int.append(len(st))
```

Additionally, the line `st=s[n]` isn't quite right. Consider the input `dvdf`. As you walk through it `st` will change from `''` to `'d'` to `'dv'`, and finally we'll find the character `s[2] == 'd'` which is already in `st`. We should be trying to start over starting at `v` to eventually find `vdf`, but we're instead just starting at the current character. One (expensive) way to fix that is in the else block find the location of the *last* appearance of the repeat and work from there. I.e., instead of `st=s[n]` do something like the following:

```
i = -1  # doesn't really matter
for j, c in enumerate(st):
    if c==s[n]:
        i = j
st = st[i+1:] + s[n]
```

Putting it all together you get something like this:

```
def len_of_substring(s): 
    list_int = []
    st = ''

    for n in range(0, len(s)): 
        if s[n] not in st:
            st=st+str(s[n])
            list_int.append(len(st))
        else:
            st = st[st.rfind(s[n])+1:] + s[n]
    if st:
        list_int.append(len(st))
    return(max(list_int))
```

Once you get it working there are some other performance and style problems. You might want to post the finished code to the [code review stackexchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).